# Shell out diff with input redirection in Golang

Tags: shell, go

I'm trying to shell out something similar to:

```
diff  <(echo -e "$string1" ) <(echo -e "$string2")
```

in Golang but all my attempts with `exec.Command` have failed.

Here is the most naive attempt I have tried (`CombinedOutput` is temporarily used to get the underlying issue):

```
func Diff(str1, str2 string) (string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command("diff", sanitize(str1), sanitize(str2))
    bytes, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    result := string(bytes)
    if err != nil {
        switch err.(type) {
        case *exec.ExitError:
            return result, nil
        default:
            return "", nil
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

Which gives me results such as: `diff: \"foo\nbar\nbaz\": No such file or directory
diff: \"foo\nfighters\nbaz\": No such file or directory`

A more involved version still does not work:

```
func Diff(str1, str2 string) (string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command("diff")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    io.WriteString(stdin, echoString(str1))
    io.WriteString(stdin, echoString(str2))
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
    cmd.Wait()
    result := string(bytes)
    if err != nil {
        switch err.(type) {
        case *exec.ExitError:
            return result, nil
        default:
            return "", nil
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}

func echoString(str string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(`<( echo -e "%s" )`, strings.Replace(str, `"`, `\"`, -1))
}
```

There is no output at all and I get `` diff: missing operand after `diff'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information. `` in `stderr`.

So I thought I did not really need the `echo` instructions because I already got the strings, so I tried to replace `echoString` implementation with just the escape part, i.e. `` return strings.Replace(str, `"`, `\"`, -1) `` but I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you paste your code and the error message, we might be able to help better

Comment: Added the most naive version of what I've tried.

Comment: Well, diff command expects files as its arguments, not just strings, so thats why you are getting the error you are getting

Comment: I know and I don't expect the naive version to work at all, but I fiddled around stdin and could not find a way to code the shell input redirection in Go.

Comment: I just added a more complex version as well

Comment: The problem with the second version is that `<(echo "string")` is a piece of code that is interpreted by the shell, but you are running diff directly without any shell in between. Try to run the whole thing as a command argument to the shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182534/discussion-between-rolf-and-mad-wombat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is simplest solution, just pass `diff` command to `bash` shell:

```
    cmd := exec.Command(
        "bash", "-c", 
        fmt.Sprintf("diff <(echo -e %s) <(echo -e %s)", str1, str2))
```

Comment: Ah, clever! I just pass the whole diff command as a string to bash. Nice find!